# What would happen if you accidentally casually put your apple watch on a wireless charger meant for phones or other higher power devices for hours?

Tags: wireless, inductive, wireless-charging

What would happen if you accidentally, casually (because they're supposed to be so convenient!) put your apple watch on a wireless charger meant for phones or other higher power devices for hours? Or rather, what are the general things to take note of regarding compatibility of such wireless chargers?

Comment: This question is not on topic here, as it concerns the *usage* of consumer products.  Only *design* questions which can be considered in the context of engineering detail *presented with the question itself* fit here.  In the case of the types of consumer products you are talking about, many of the key details are intentionally kept secret by the manufacturer, and even if they were not, needing to chase them down does not fit with what this site is about.

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid wasting power, wireless chargers only activate when a compatible device communicates with the charger.

Comment: Plus, the actual charging circuit is inside the watch. It will only draw as much power from the field as it needs. It won't overcharge the battery or anything.

Answer (score 1):

For major brands, compatibility will be a major thing, for example, if you put your apple watch on a non apple wireless charger, it's not going to charge. There may be some products that will charge from multiple wireless chargers, but this will not really be an issue.

The next thing is that the device *to be charged* is the one that has the charging circuit in it. The device will only draw the power that it *needs*. This is why an iPhone and an iPad can share the same charger, even though both require different amounts of current (or they did a few years back, I'm not too up to date with Apple any more!)

So in summary, you will be fine. If it is an Apple device, chances are it will only work with a compatible Apple charger. The charging circuit inside the device will only draw the power it needs to charge.